# NVD3 Handling NaN values in interactive graphs

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

NVD3 graphs involving tooltips seem to be facing problems dealing with NaN values.
Though `nv.models.line` has:

`defined = function(d,i) { return !isNaN(getY(d,i)) && getY(d,i) !== null } // allows a line to be not continuous when it is not defined`

However, when trying to use for e.g. `lineChart`, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'circle' of null d3.v3.min.js:1` and tooltips never get displayed.

Trace:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'circle' of null d3.v3.min.js:1`

`cr d3.v3.min.js:1`

`nr d3.v3.min.js:1`

`_r d3.v3.min.js:2`

`t d3.v3.min.js:4`

`$o.geom.voronoi d3.v3.min.js:4`

`updateInteractiveLayer nv.d3.js:7963`

Here's the jsfiddle for this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ixaxaar/sm3jE/9/)

Any solutions?

Comment: The comment indicates that this only applies to lines (and indeed the line is drawn with several segments). To make it work for the circles/tooltips as well, you would have to modify the NVD3 source.

Comment: ah, let me try that :D